# Get JTextArea current row text on Enter Key

Tags: java, swing, document, jtextarea, caret

Well, this is a small problem maybe, but I couldn't figure it.
I want my program display the text in current cursor position when I press the Enter key.
Here's my current code:

```
if (evt.getKeyCode() == 10) {
  try {
    int offset=ta.getLineOfOffset(ta.getCaretPosition());
    int start=ta.getLineStartOffset(offset);
    int end=ta.getLineEndOffset(offset);

    System.out.println("ext: "+ta.getText(start, end));

  } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
  }
}
```

It works only for the first time I press the Enter key, the next time I press it, it throws an exception "Invalid Location".
Any better way to do this?

Comment: Pressing enter acts as a submit operation and the caret disappears - that's why you are getting Invalid Operation. By the time you press Enter for the second time, there is no caret in the TextArea.

Comment: hmm, then what do you suggest me to fix this one?

Comment: You might save the last known caret position and return that. Or after an Enter (which fires an Action that can be processed in an ActionListener) you progrmatically set the caret to its original position.

Comment: could you provide an example @JakubZaverka? I'm confussed about this one..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hhehe, solved it by myself:

Here's the correct code for what I'm looking for:

```
if (evt.getKeyCode() == 10) {
  try {
    int offset=ta.getLineOfOffset(ta.getCaretPosition());
    int start=ta.getLineStartOffset(offset);
    int end=ta.getLineEndOffset(offset);

    System.out.println("Text: "+ta.getText(start, (end-start)));                
  } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
  }
}
```

Maybe it's useful to another guy out there :)